# What is the difference between these two codes? (Python: circular singly linked list)

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, linked-list

These are the codes for __iter__ method of a circular singly linked list. But I don't understand the difference between the two.

```
def __iter__(self):
    node = self.head
    while node:     # i.e. while node is not None
        yield node
        if node.next == self.head:   # i.e. if node.next refers to the first node, i.e. if that is the last node, break
            break       # without this if condition, the loop will loop forever
        node = node.next
```

and

```
def __iter__(self):
    node = self.head
    while node:
        yield node
        node = node.next
        if node == self.tail.next:
            break
```

Comment: Presumable, the node after `self.tail` is `self.head`, but you haven't given a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
def __iter__(self):
    node = self.head
    while node:     # i.e. while node is not None
        yield node
        if node.next == self.head:   # i.e. if node.next refers to the first node, i.e. if that is the last node, break
            break       # without this if condition, the loop will loop forever
        node = node.next
```

This `if` condition doesn't garantee to stop loop over.
There is no way `node.next` is equal to `self.head` in the above code.
However, as the node will update for every iteration, it will stop the iterations when it reachs `node==null`

```
def __iter__(self):
    node = self.head
    while node:
        yield node
        node = node.next
        if node == self.tail.next:
            break
```

** this code is the same as:**

```
def __iter__(self):
    node = self.head
    while node:
        yield node
        node = node.next
        if node == None:
            break
```

As `node.tail` is the last element in the linked list, `node.tail.next` would be `None`.
node.tail